# How can I get the selected check item in the listView and pass the value to next activity?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

1. The problem is when I click the checkbox, the **CurrentSelectedItems** don't get items.
2. Before I add **onItemCheck**,,, **onItemUnCheck**,,,**private ClickListener onItemCheckListener**,,, **private final ClickListener onItemClick**,,,  **this.onItemClick = onItemCheckListener** and....  **(holder).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener())** . It should allow onclick on the Item in recyclerView, but after I add these, it direct disconnect. What is the Problem ?

-- In the Main Activity

```
    lodgingAdapter.setOnItemClickListener( new LodgingAdapter.ClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(int position, View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(FavouriteLodging.this, ViewFavouriteDetails.class);
            intent.putExtra("UserID", getIntent().getStringExtra("UserID"));
            intent.putExtra("LodgingID", ll.get(position).getLodgingId());
            startActivity(intent);
        }

       @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(int position, View v) {
            return true;

        }
```

-- The CurrentSelectedItems didn't add the item.

```
        @Override
        public void onItemCheck(Lodging item) {
            currentSelectedItems.add(item);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemUncheck(Lodging item) {
            currentSelectedItems.add(item);

        }
    });
```

-- My Adapter

public class LodgingAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter{

```
private List<Lodging> ll;
private static ClickListener clickListener;
private static int CHECKED_BOX_MAXIMUM = 0;


public interface ClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int position, View v);
    boolean onItemLongClick(int position, View v);
    void onItemCheck(Lodging item);
    void onItemUncheck(Lodging item);
}

@NonNull
private ClickListener onItemCheckListener;
private final ClickListener onItemClick;

public LodgingAdapter(List<Lodging> LodgingList) {
    ll = LodgingList;
    this.onItemClick = onItemCheckListener;
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener,CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener{

    public TextView title;
    public TextView price;
    public TextView type;
    public ImageView picture;
    public CheckBox cbBox;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);
        v.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        title = v.findViewById(R.id.titleTv);
        price = v.findViewById(R.id.priceTv);
        type = v.findViewById(R.id.lodgingTypeTv);
        picture = v.findViewById(R.id.lodgingPicIv);
        cbBox = v.findViewById(R.id.cbCompare);
        cbBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    }

   public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener onClickListener) {
        itemView.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    }

    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        clickListener.onItemLongClick(getAdapterPosition(), view);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        clickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), view);
    }
```

If the checkbox is clicked then CHECKED_BOX_MAXIMUM++, else CHECKED_BOX_MAXIMUM-- and when two checkbox has been clicked then other checkbox is unclickable.

```
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        switch (buttonView.getId()){
            case R.id.cbCompare :
                if(isChecked == true){
                    CHECKED_BOX_MAXIMUM++;
                }else{
                    CHECKED_BOX_MAXIMUM--;
                }if (isChecked && CHECKED_BOX_MAXIMUM > 2) {
                     cbBox.setChecked(false);
                     CHECKED_BOX_MAXIMUM--;
            }
        }
    }


}



public void setOnItemClickListener(ClickListener clickListener) {
    LodgingAdapter.clickListener = clickListener;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final LodgingAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final Lodging l = ll.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(l.getTitle());
        holder.price.setText("RM" + String.format("%.2f", l.getPrice()));
        holder.type.setText(l.getLodgingType());
      (holder).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                (holder).cbBox.setChecked(!(holder).cbBox.isChecked());
                if ((holder).cbBox.isChecked()) {
                    onItemClick.onItemCheck(l);
                } else {
                    onItemClick.onItemUncheck(l);
                }
            }
        });

        Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext())
                .load(l.getImage())
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                .skipMemoryCache(true)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(holder.picture);


}
```

}

[This is My First UI,  CLICK ME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65DKo.png).

[After clicking the checkbox, it suppose to pass here one will show on the top and the other will show the bottom.  CLICK ME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GI67p.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the adapter class create a function that returns the list of selected items.

And in the activity call the function when the menu item is clicked , here make the comparison of the size of the returned list  >=2 and if true intent it as in function `SelectedItem()`

Comment: Hi, I really new to android. Can you give me some example. I already find alot of solution, but not one can solve it ...